# Need help creating lists

Tags: java, arrays

I need help for a project that requires creating lists upong a String. Let's say for example I have the next string

```
(defun sum(+ 1 2))
```

What I need to do is turn that string into an array, which I have already done using the the split method.

So now, I want to check the whole array in look for `(`. if the loop finds a `(` it creates an array/list and appends the following elements. But if the loop finds a `)` it stops adding elements to the last array/list created, but it continues to add in the other list. I want my program to do that until there is no more elements to add (or well, when the whole string was separated into lists). Right now this is what I have:

```
public ArrayList<String> SaveInLists(String command) {
        String delimiter = "(";
        ArrayList<String> list_global = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] commandlist = command.split("");
        for(int i = 0;i<commandlist.length;i++){
            if(commandlist[i].equals("(")){
                //create new arraylist and add the next elements of commandlist to the array until it finds a ')'.
                //then it closes the arraylist, but keep adding the other elements next to ')'
            }
        }
        //then all the arrays created need to be added to the list_global
        return list_global;
    }
```

Comment: LISP? Java? Make your choice.

Comment: Need to make a Lisp interpreter using java

Comment: but the key is by doing the thing I just explained

Comment: I would remove the common-lisp tag.  Your question is about Java.

Comment: I can immensely recommend to use a lexer/parser tool like Antlr, they are specifically designed to avoid introducing people to the complexity of parsers for programming languages while still keeping the majority of the information that you'd need. try https://www.antlr.org/ and https://gist.github.com/schwede/d4985fdc981985ef0cba205d00611072 ... tools like IntelliJ also have plugins to make Antlr easier to use

Answer (score 0):

This how my proposed solution could look like. As far as I understand the resulting global list must be represented as the list of inner lists, not just an `ArrayList<String>`, because in this case we don't have any inner lists, just an array of strings. So, I thought the resulting global list must be of `List<List<String>>` data type. Below is the possible implementation:

```
public List<List<String>> saveInLists(String command) {
    if (command == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input command cannot be null!");
    }

    List<List<String>> globalList = new ArrayList<>();
    String openingDelimiter = "(";
    String closingDelimiter = ")";
    String[] commandList = command.split("");

    int openDelimitersCount = 0;
    int closingDelimiterCount = 0;

    int innerListsCount = 0; int lastInnerListIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < commandList.length; i++) {
        if (openingDelimiter.equals(commandList[i])) {
            // the next inner list should be created for adding "non-bracket" elements
            innerListsCount++;
            lastInnerListIndex++;
            List<String> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
            globalList.add(innerList);

            openDelimitersCount++;
        } else if (closingDelimiter.equals(commandList[i])) {
            // the next "non-bracket" elements should be added to the previous list
            lastInnerListIndex--;
            closingDelimiterCount++;
        } else {
            // it's not a bracket, it's some other "non-bracket" element
            if (innerListsCount == 0) {
                // no brackets at the beginning of the sequence, so we should create the very first list
                innerListsCount++;
                lastInnerListIndex++;
                List<String> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
                innerList.add(commandList[i]);
                globalList.add(innerList);
            } else {
                // we already have some inner list
                if (lastInnerListIndex < 0) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Last inner list index reached negative value!");
                }
                List<String> lastInnerList = globalList.get(lastInnerListIndex);
                lastInnerList.add(commandList[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (openDelimitersCount != closingDelimiterCount) {
        // you can check here and throw an exception in case there's some mismatch regarding the count of ( and )
        throw new RuntimeException("The count of ( and ) brackets in the input expression does not match!");
    }

    // return the global list of inner lists
    return globalList;
}
```

The usage of this method and sample cases:

```
    List<List<String>> result1 = saveInLists("(defun sum(+ 1 2))");
    System.out.println(result1);
    // 2 inner lists inside global list: [[d, e, f, u, n,  , s, u, m], [+,  , 1,  , 2]]

    List<List<String>> result2 = saveInLists("(defun sum(+ 1 2) a bc d)");
    System.out.println(result2);
    // 2 inner lists inside global list: [[d, e, f, u, n,  , s, u, m,  , a,  , b, c,  , d], [+,  , 1,  , 2]]

    List<List<String>> result3 = saveInLists("defun sum(+ 1 2) a bc d");
    System.out.println(result3);
    // The same as previous, despite the absence of outer brackets pair: [[d, e, f, u, n,  , s, u, m,  , a,  , b, c,  , d], [+,  , 1,  , 2]]

    List<List<String>> result4 = saveInLists("(defun sum(+ 1 2 (some internal expr)) a bc d)");
    System.out.println(result4);
    // 3 inner lists inside global list: [[d, e, f, u, n,  , s, u, m,  , a,  , b, c,  , d], [+,  , 1,  , 2,  ], [s, o, m, e,  , i, n, t, e, r, n, a, l,  , e, x, p, r]]

    List<List<String>> result5 = saveInLists("defun sum(+ 1 2 (some internal expr)) a bc d)");
    System.out.println(result5);
    // this will throw an exception, because we're missing the very first opening bracket.
```

Please, let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: Some addition: if it's desired, some duplicated parts of code above, where we create an inner list can (and, frankly speaking, _must_) be extracted to a separate method to avoid presence of duplicated code in `saveInLists` method.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation can be the following one:

```java
public List<String> saveInLists(String command) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer> startPositions = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < command.length(); i++) {
        if (command.charAt(i) == '(') {
            startPositions.addFirst(i);
        } else if (command.charAt(i) == ')') {
            result.add(command.substring(startPositions.removeFirst(), i + 1));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Every time `(` is found the start position is saved in the `startPositions` list and every time `)` is found the substring is saved in the `result` list.

Notice that you can access the command string directly like a char array.

Example:

```
(defun sum(+ 1 (- 5 2) 2))
```

Output:

```
["(- 5 2)", "(+ 1 (- 5 2) 2)", "(defun sum(+ 1 (- 5 2) 2))"]
```